# Linking the results of an SQL query to a kbmMemtable in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I've trying to fix a portion of an old program written in Delphi 7.

At the moment, I have the correct query (and the correct results), but I can't figure out how to display the results in a kbmMemtable (which is what the rest of the application uses)

Any ideas / suggestions / links to pertinent documentation?

Comment: I edited your question to remove improper formatting and your signature, then rolled back your re-edit, since you got it to it's original state, please, don't do that!

Comment: Signatures are not allowed here. You have an entire profile if you want to provide personal information about yourself; please use it instead. Signatures in questions simply waste space and add clutter.

Comment: Do you have a licensed copy of the KBMMemTable (which would include the documentation)? If so, it contains info about doing this; if not, you can download samples from the C4D website by just signing up there, IIRC. (One of the shortcomings of the C4D stuff, IMO, is that they give away a free version of KBMMemTable but don't provide any documentation unless you purchase the full version - it makes it hard to evaluate properly if you don't have the docs available.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how I ended up messing up both the formatting and the signature...

Ken, we do, but we're not sure where it is as the moment. I sent an email to C4D and am waiting on a response... Thanks for the input though :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing the results are in some kind of `TDataset` descendant.
So, your first option would be `kbmObject.LoadFromDataset(resultsObject, options)`, where `options` is a set of `TkbmMemTableCopyTableOption`. Basically, you are specifying how you want to move the data from one object to another. Since I don't know your code, I can't say what options you should use, but I usually use `[mtcpoStructure]` - copies the source field structure to a newly created `TkbmMemTable` and then appends all the records.

But you also have `kbmObject.CopyData(kbmObject, resultsObject, Count)`, which assumes you already created the field structure in your `kbmObject`.

Comment: We're actually using `kbmObject.LoadFromDataSet(resultsObject, [mtcpoAppend])` (And while this works for all the other kbmObjects listed in the function, the new one I added `mtChapFollowUpInfoAll` does allow me to display the result set.)